# jquery autocomplete - add custom class

Tags: jquery, css, class, autocomplete

Does anyone know how I can integrate a custom class here in 'MYCODE'? I seem to have
a working snippet, but not sure where excactly it goes here.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
The snippet is working on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/rMhVz/2/

SNIPPET:

```
$("input").autocomplete({source: data}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var listItem = $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);

    if (item.class != "") {
        listItem.addClass(item.class);
    }

    return listItem;
};
```

MYCODE:

```
$( "#phraseId" ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) {

if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
$( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
event.preventDefault();
}
})
.autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
$.getJSON( "search.php", {
term: extractLast( request.term )
}, response );
},
search: function() {
// custom minLength
var term = extractLast( this.value );
if ( term.length < 2 ) {
return false;
}
},
focus: function() {
// prevent value inserted on focus
return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {

var terms = split( this.value );
// remove the current input
terms.pop();
// add the selected item
terms.push( ui.item.value );
// add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
terms.push( "" );
this.value = terms.join( " " );

return false;
}
});
});
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the custom class...

Comment: I want to display a flag symbol for that list item, to visualize where the client is from (eg. USA, Switzerland etc.)

Comment: do you mean ` if (item.class != "") {
        listItem.addClass(item.class);
    }` is not working?

Comment: No, I don't seem to place the 'SNIPPET' right inside 'MYCODE'. Where does it go?